# Verifying a string is UTF-8 encoded in Java

Tags: java, string, encoding, utf-8, utf-16

There are plenty of  to how to check if a string is UTF-8 encoded, for example:

```
public static boolean isUTF8(String s){
    try{
        byte[]bytes = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
    }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    return true;
}
```

The doc of `java.lang.String#getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset)` says:

> This method always replaces malformed-input and unmappable-character sequences with this charset's default replacement byte array.

1. Is it correct that it always returns correct UTF-8 bytes?
2. Does it make sense to perform such checks on `String` objects at all? 
   Won't it always be returning `true` as a String object is already encoded?
3. As far as I understand such checks should be performed on bytes, not on `String` objects:

```
public static final boolean isUTF8(final byte[] inputBytes) {
    final String converted = new String(inputBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    final byte[] outputBytes = converted.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    return Arrays.equals(inputBytes, outputBytes);
}
```

But in this case I'm not sure I understand where I should take those butes from as getting it straight from the `String` object will no be correct.

Comment: A String is a sequence of characters. Encoding starts to matter when you want to transform a string to bytes, or bytes to a String, because the encoding defines which characters can be encoded, and how they are transformed to bytes (and vice-versa). So "checking if a String is UTF-8 encoded" doesn't make sense

Answer (score 5):

> Is it correct that it always returns correct UTF-8 bytes?

Yes.

> Does it make sense to perform such checks on String objects at all? Won't it always be returning true as a String object is already encoded?

Java strings use Unicode characters encoded in UTF-16. Since UTF-16 uses surrogate pairs, any *unpaired surrogate* is invalid, so Java strings can contain invalid `char` sequences.

Java strings can also contain characters that are unassigned in Unicode.

Which means that performing validation on a Java `String` makes sense, though it is very rarely done.

> As far as I understand such checks should be performed on bytes, not on String objects.

Depending on the character set of the bytes, there is nothing to validate, e.g. character set CP437 maps all 256 byte values, so it cannot be invalid.

UTF-8 can be invalid, so you're correct that validating bytes is useful.

---

As the javadoc said, `getBytes(Charset)` always replaces malformed-input and unmappable-character sequences with the charset's default replacement byte.

That is because it does this:

```
CharsetEncoder encoder = charset.newEncoder()
        .onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)
        .onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE);
```

If you want to get the bytes, but fail on malformed-input and unmappable-character sequences, use `CodingErrorAction.REPORT` instead. Since that's actually the default, simply don't call the two `onXxx()` methods.

*Example*

```
String s = "\uD800"; // unpaired surrogate
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
```

That prints `[63]` which is a `?`, i.e. the unpaired surrogate is malformed-input, so it was replaced with the replacement byte.

```
String s = "\uD800"; // unpaired surrogate

CharsetEncoder encoder = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newEncoder();
ByteBuffer encoded = encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(s.toCharArray()));
byte[] bytes = new byte[encoded.remaining()];
encoded.get(bytes);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
```

That causes `MalformedInputException: Input length = 1` since the default malformed-input action is `REPORT`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, the last example doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: it looks like unpaired surrogate `\uD800` will automatically be converted into question mark, that's why it doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: @void I just ran the last block of code (the one with 6 statements), and it threw the exception, on both Java 7 and Java 13, on Windows. The 2 statement block of code right below the *Example* text doesn't throw exception, as already stated in the answer.

Comment: for me (osx, java 8) it throws an exception if encoding the array of chars without putting them into a string first, so this fails `encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(new char[]{'\uD800'}))` while this succeeds `encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap("\uD800".toCharArray()));`

Answer (score 2):

Your function as shown makes no sense.  As the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.lang.String)) says:

> **A `String` represents a string in the UTF-16 format** in which *supplementary characters* are represented by *surrogate pairs* (see the section [Unicode Character Representations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode) in the `Character` class for more information). Index values refer to `char` code units, so a supplementary character uses two positions in a `String`.

A `String` is comprised of UTF-16 encoded characters, not UTF-8.  A `String` will NEVER be encoded in UTF-8, but it can ALWAYS be converted to UTF-8, so your function will ALWAYS return `true`.  "UTF-8" is a standard encoding supported by all Java implementations, so `getBytes("UTF-8")` will NEVER throw `UnsupportedEncodingException`, which is raised only when an unsupported charset is used.

Your function would make more sense only if it took a `byte[]` as input instead.  But even then, doing a double-encode and comparing the results is not efficient.  As the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.lang.String)) says:

> The behavior of this constructor when the given bytes are not valid in the given charset is unspecified. **The [`CharsetDecoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) class should be used when more control over the decoding process is required.**

For example:

```java
public static boolean isUTF8(byte[] bytes){
    try{
        StandardCharset.UTF_8.newDecoder()
         .onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT)
         .onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT)
         .decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes)); 
    }
    catch (CharacterCodingException e){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this

```
    public static boolean isUTF8(String input) {
        return StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newEncoder().canEncode(input);
    }
```

Internally the `canEncode` is already handling the REPORT and is handling the exceptions.

```
    private boolean canEncode(CharBuffer cb) {
        if (state == ST_FLUSHED)
            reset();
        else if (state != ST_RESET)
            throwIllegalStateException(state, ST_CODING);
        CodingErrorAction ma = malformedInputAction();
        CodingErrorAction ua = unmappableCharacterAction();
        try {
            onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
            onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
            encode(cb);
        } catch (CharacterCodingException x) {
            return false;
        } finally {
            onMalformedInput(ma);
            onUnmappableCharacter(ua);
            reset();
        }
        return true;
    }
```